# Magnitude in complex sum of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, 3d, projection

> If $\vec{a}=\hat{i}+2\hat{j}+3\hat{k}$ and $\vec{b}=2\hat{i}+3\hat{j}+2\hat{k}$ and $\vec{c}$ be a vector non collinear with $\vec{b}.$ Find magnitude of
>
> $$
> \frac{\vec{a} \cdot (\vec{b}\times \vec{c})}{|\vec{b}\times \vec{c}|^2}(\vec{b}\times \vec{c})+\frac{(\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b})\vec{b}}{|\vec{b}|^2}+\frac{(\vec{a}\cdot \vec{c})\vec{c}}{|\vec{c}|^2}
> $$

**What I tried:**

Vector component of $\vec{a}$ along $\displaystyle \vec{c}=(|\vec{a}|\cos \alpha)\hat{c}=\frac{(\vec{a}\cdot \vec{c})}{|\vec{c}|^2}\vec{c}$

Vector component of $\vec{a}$ along $\displaystyle \vec{b}=(|\vec{a}|\cos \beta)\hat{b}=\frac{(\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b})}{|\vec{b}|^2}\vec{b}$

Vector component of $\vec{a}$ along $$\displaystyle \vec{b }\times\vec{c}=(|\vec{a}|\cos \gamma)(\hat{b}\times \hat{c})=\frac{(\vec{a}\cdot (\vec{b}\times\vec{c}))}{|\vec{b}\times\vec{c}|^2}{(\vec{b}\times \vec{c})}$$

How do I solve it?
Help me please.

Answer (score 2):

As @MMM says, the result is not pretty in general. To illustrate this, I wrote a *Mathematica* script which assumes $\vec{c}=x\hat{i}+y\hat{j}+z\hat{k}$ where $x,y,z$ are real numbers.

```
a = {1, 2, 3}; b = {2, 3, 2}; c = {x, y, z};
d = a.Cross[b,c]/Norm[Cross[b,c]]^2 Cross[b,c] + a.b/Norm[b]^2 b + a.c/Norm[c]^2 c;
```

And then

```
Assuming[x\[Element]Reals && y\[Element]Reals && z\[Element]Reals, Simplify[d]]
```

which yields
$$\vec{d}=\left(\frac{x (x+2 y+3 z)}{x^2+y^2+z^2}+\frac{(2 y-3 z) (5 x-4 y+z)}{13 x^2-4 x (3 y+2 z)+8 y^2-12 y z+13 z^2}+\frac{28}{17}\right)\hat{i}\\+\left(\frac{y (x+2 y+3 z)}{x^2+y^2+z^2}-\frac{2 (x-z) (5 x-4 y+z)}{(3 x-2 y)^2+4 (x-z)^2+(2 y-3 z)^2}+\frac{42}{17}\right)\hat{j}\\+\left(\frac{z (x+2 y+3 z)}{x^2+y^2+z^2}+\frac{(3 x-2 y) (5 x-4 y+z)}{(3 x-2 y)^2+4 (x-z)^2+(2 y-3 z)^2}+\frac{28}{17}\right)\hat{k}$$
It is evident that the magnitude of such vector is far from pretty. But just to be sure,

```
Assuming[x\[Element]Reals && y\[Element]Reals && z\[Element]Reals, Simplify[Norm[d]]]
```

results in
$$|\vec{d}|=\sqrt{\frac{P(x,y,z)}{Q(x,y,z)}}$$
where
$$P=3922 x^4+3728 y^4+6738 z^4+x^3 (2256 z-476 y)+x^2 \left(5297 y^2-2004 y z+8052 z^2\right)-2 x \left(1876 y^3+5331 y^2 z+5954 y z^2-136 z^3\right)-776 y^3 z+3225 y^2 z^2+1044 y z^3,\text{ and}\\
Q=17 \left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right) \left(13 x^2-4 x (3 y+2 z)+8 y^2-12 y z+13 z^2\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Simple case (Good case):  $\vec{c}$ is perpendicular to $\vec{b}$.

In that case, the answer is $\sqrt 14$. The complicated looking expression is another way of expressing the vector $\mathbb{a}$ in terms of the new basis of $\mathbb{R^3}$ that is {$\vec{b} \times \vec{c}, \vec{b}, \vec{c}$}. In this case, these three vectors are orthogonal to each other. So, we can form an orthonormal basis, and my solution will work.

General Case: $\vec{c}$ is not necesarly perpendicular to $\vec{b}$.

In this case, there should not be any good looking/simple answer. If someone does some ugly computation, s/he will get an ugly expression that depends on the choice of $\mathbb{c}$. I believe that should not be a good/interesting question.

Conclusion: There is no good looking/simple expression for the magnitude of this complicated vector which is independent of $c$.

Comment: For $\vec{c}=\hat{i}$, the magnitude is $\sqrt{\frac{3922}{221}}$ which is not equal to $\sqrt{14}$.

Comment: @mathlove thanks so much. I edited my answer.  I found the gap in my initial arguments. The basis was not orthonormal.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Here we do not take the given values of $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$, but look instead at the structural representation in  a real vector space which might help to better see what's going on. For  convenience only we use angle brackets $\langle \ldots ,\ldots\rangle$ to denote the dot-product.

> We calculate the *square* of the magnitude and obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> &\color{blue}{\left|\left\langle\vec{a},\frac{\vec{b}\times \vec{c}}{\left|\vec{b}\times\vec{c}\right|}\right\rangle
> \frac{\vec{b}\times \vec{c}}{\left|\vec{b}\times\vec{c}\right|}
> +\left\langle\vec{a},\frac{\vec{b}}{\left|\vec{b}\right|}\right\rangle\frac{\vec{b}}{\left|\vec{b}\right|}
> +\left\langle\vec{a},\frac{\vec{c}}{\left|\vec{c}\right|}\right\rangle\frac{\vec{c}}{\left|\vec{c}\right|}\right|^{\,2}}\\
> &=\left\langle
> \left\langle\vec{a},\frac{\vec{b}\times \vec{c}}{\left|\vec{b}\times\vec{c}\right|}\right\rangle
> \frac{\vec{b}\times \vec{c}}{\left|\vec{b}\times\vec{c}\right|}
> +\left\langle\vec{a},\frac{\vec{b}}{\left|\vec{b}\right|}\right\rangle\frac{\vec{b}}{\left|\vec{b}\right|}
> +\left\langle\vec{a},\frac{\vec{c}}{\left|\vec{c}\right|}\right\rangle\frac{\vec{c}}{\left|\vec{c}\right|},\right.\\
> &\qquad\left.\left\langle\vec{a},\frac{\vec{b}\times \vec{c}}{\left|\vec{b}\times\vec{c}\right|}\right\rangle
> \frac{\vec{b}\times \vec{c}}{\left|\vec{b}\times\vec{c}\right|}
> +\left\langle\vec{a},\frac{\vec{b}}{\left|\vec{b}\right|}\right\rangle\frac{\vec{b}}{\left|\vec{b}\right|}
> +\left\langle\vec{a},\frac{\vec{c}}{\left|\vec{c}\right|}\right\rangle\frac{\vec{c}}{\left|\vec{c}\right|}
> \right\rangle\tag{1}\\
> &=\left\langle\vec{a},\frac{\vec{b}\times \vec{c}}{\left|\vec{b}\times\vec{c}\right|}\right\rangle^2
> \left\langle\frac{\vec{b}\times \vec{c}}{\left|\vec{b}\times\vec{c}\right|},\frac{\vec{b}\times \vec{c}}{\left|\vec{b}\times\vec{c}\right|}\right\rangle\\
> &\qquad+\left\langle\vec{a},\frac{\vec{b}}{\left|\vec{b}\right|}\right\rangle^2
> \left\langle\frac{\vec{b}}{\left|\vec{b}\right|},\frac{\vec{b}}{\left|\vec{b}\right|}\right\rangle
> +\left\langle\vec{a},\frac{\vec{b}}{\left|\vec{b}\right|}\right\rangle
> \left\langle\vec{a},\frac{\vec{c}}{\left|\vec{c}\right|}\right\rangle
> \left\langle\frac{\vec{b}}{\left|\vec{b}\right|},\frac{\vec{c}}{\left|\vec{c}\right|}\right\rangle\\
> &\qquad+\left\langle\vec{a},\frac{\vec{c}}{\left|\vec{c}\right|}\right\rangle
> \left\langle\vec{a},\frac{\vec{b}}{\left|\vec{b}\right|}\right\rangle
> \left\langle\frac{\vec{c}}{\left|\vec{c}\right|},\frac{\vec{b}}{\left|\vec{b}\right|}\right\rangle
> +\left\langle\vec{a},\frac{\vec{c}}{\left|\vec{c}\right|}\right\rangle^2
> \left\langle\frac{\vec{c}}{\left|\vec{c}\right|},\frac{\vec{c}}{\left|\vec{c}\right|}\right\rangle\tag{2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\left\langle\vec{a},\frac{\vec{b}\times \vec{c}}{\left|\vec{b}\times\vec{c}\right|}\right\rangle^2
> +\left\langle\vec{a},\frac{\vec{b}}{\left|\vec{b}\right|}\right\rangle^2
> +2\left\langle\vec{a},\frac{\vec{b}}{\left|\vec{b}\right|}\right\rangle
> \left\langle\vec{a},\frac{\vec{c}}{\left|\vec{c}\right|}\right\rangle
> \left\langle\frac{\vec{b}}{\left|\vec{b}\right|},\frac{\vec{c}}{\left|\vec{c}\right|}\right\rangle
> +\left\langle\vec{a},\frac{\vec{c}}{\left|\vec{c}\right|}\right\rangle^2}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we write the square of the magnitude as dot-product: $|\vec{z}|^2=\langle \vec{z},\vec{z}\rangle$.
- In (2) we multiply  out  according to
  \begin{align*}
  &\langle  \vec{x}+\vec{y}+\vec{z},\vec{x}+\vec{y}+\vec{z}   \rangle\\
  &\quad=\langle  \vec{x},\vec{x}\rangle
  +\langle  \vec{x},\vec{y} \rangle
  +\langle  \vec{x},\vec{z}   \rangle\\
  &\quad\quad+\langle \vec{y},\vec{x} \rangle
  +\langle \vec{y},\vec{y}  \rangle
  +\langle \vec{y},\vec{z}   \rangle\\
  &\qquad\qquad+\langle \vec{z},\vec{x}   \rangle
  +\langle  \vec{z},\vec{y}  \rangle
  +\langle  \vec{z},\vec{z}  \rangle
  \end{align*}
  and  use the orthogonal property of the cross product
  \begin{align*}
  \langle \vec{b}\times \vec{c},\vec{b}\rangle=\langle \vec{b}\times \vec{c},\vec{c}\rangle
  =\langle\vec{b}, \vec{b}\times \vec{c}\rangle=\langle\vec{c}, \vec{b}\times \vec{c}\rangle=\vec{0}\\
  \end{align*}
  which significantly reduces the  number of terms.
- In (3) we use that the magnitude of unit vectors $\left|\frac{\vec{z}}{\left|\vec{z}\right|}\right|=1$ reducing the number of factors. We also use the symmetry of the dot-product $\langle \vec{x},\vec{y}\rangle=\langle\vec{y},\vec{x}\rangle$.

Comment: Isn't this the good ol' factorization/expansion of the three terms square? $$(m+n+p)^2=m^2+n^2+p^2+2(mn+np+pm)$$ where $mn=mp=0$

Comment: @polfosol: In this context I would rather argue with the bilinearity properties of the dot product. But the similarity is clear.

Answer (score -1):

**HINT**

Let $\vec{z} = \vec{b} \times \vec{c}$. Note that $\vec{b}, \vec{c}$ are not collinear, so $\vec{z} \perp \vec{b}$ and $\vec{z} \perp \vec{c}$ and so $\mathcal{B} = \{\vec{z}, \vec{b}, \vec{c}\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Each component of your sum is basically the projection of $\vec{a}$ on each of the elements of that basis $\mathcal{B}$, so the end result should be **very** related to $a$. Can you finish the problem now?

**UPDATE**

If $a,b$ are some vectors, then the projection of $a$ onto $b$ is given by
$$
p_b(a) = \frac{a \cdot b}{|b|^2} b.
$$
Note that $p_b(a)$ is always in the direction of $b$.

Now if you have a basis for some vector space, you can write any element of that vector space as a linear combination of the elements of the basis. For example, consider the standard basis in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and note that I can write any vector $(u,v)^T$ as
$$
\begin{bmatrix} u \\ v \end{bmatrix} 
 = \begin{bmatrix} u \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} 
 + \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ v \end{bmatrix} 
 = u \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} 
 + v \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} 
$$
so each element $(u,0)^T$ and $(0,v)^T$ is the projection of the original vector $(u,v)^T$ onto one of the elements of the standard basis.

Finally, in a feature unique to $\mathbb{R}^3$, if $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^3$ are non-collinear, then their cross product $x \times y$ is perpendicular to them both. Thus, the vectors $\{x,y, x \times y\}$ form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

---

Your problem sums three different terms, each of which is a projection of one vector onto the 3 elements of a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, constructed exactly through such a cross product.

When you sum the sizes of the projections, what should you get?

Comment: gt6989b did not understand . can you please explain me in detail Thanks

Comment: @jacky see an update

Comment: Thanks for your update @gt6989b.Still i did not understand How can i find my sum, please explain me final answer